# Display localized string with single/double quote in VueJS template

Tags: vue.js

I'm building a form in [Pagekit CMS](http://pagekit.com) which uses [VueJS](http://vuejs.org/). According to [Pagekit Translation guide](http://pagekit.com/docs/developer-basics/translation) to display a string in different language we use this in Vue template:

```
{{ 'Save' | trans }}
```

If there is a single quote in the string, I can't use this:

```
<label>{{ 'Map\'s width' | trans }}</label>
```

But this works:

```
<label>{{ "Map's width" | trans }}</label>
```

But how could I display a single quote in this following case?

```
 <input placeholder="{{ "Map's width" | trans }}" >
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does this works? ex: "{{  \"Map's width\" | trans }}"

Comment: @HelderLucas No it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define your strings elsewhere:

```
data: {

phrases: {

map_width: "Map's width"

}

}
```

and then use that in the template:

```
<label>{{ phrases.map_width | trans }}</label>
```